# Exclusion With Many to Many Relationships

Tags: mysql-5.6, many-to-many

I have created a select statement that show all the topics that are assigned to a book. Now I am trying to create a Select statement that shows all the topics that are not assigned to the book. Book and topic have a many to many relationship.

Problem: I am getting the topics that are assigned to other books because technically they are not assigned to my book.

In depth look: I have a database full of books. A book can have many topics and a topic can have many books. I have create a user interface for adding a book. This interface shows all the topics available when the user choose let us say three topics three records are created in the books_has_topics table one field has an id for for the book the other for the topic. I also have a user interface for updating the book. I want the user to be able to change the topics.

Code:

this works it give me a list of all the assigned to the book based on the books id.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  topic T
    INNER JOIN  book_has_topic BHT  ON T.topic_id = BHT.topic_topic_id
    WHERE  BHT.Book_book_id = [bookid];
```

This sort of works Not only do i get all the topics not assigned to the bookid I also get all the topics assigned to other books.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT topic_id, topic_name
    FROM  topic T
    LEFT JOIN  book_has_topic BHT  ON T.topic_id = BHT.topic_topic_id
    WHERE  BHT.book_book_id IS NULL
       or  BHT.book_book_id <> [bookid];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a MS SQL guy so please excuse me if my syntax is a bit off for mysql, but I would probably go with something like this.

```
SELECT topic_id, topic_name
FROM topic T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TOP 1 1
  FROM book_has_topic BHT
  WHERE BHT.topic_topic_id = topic_id
    AND BHT.book_book_id = [bookid])
```

Answer (score 0):

(`TOP` is not known to MySQL.  It's counterpart `LIMIT` is not needed.)

```
SELECT  topic_id, topic_name
    FROM topic T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM book_has_topic BHT
                 WHERE book_id = [bookid]
                   AND topic_id = T.topic_id
                     )
```

[*Tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on optimal many:many schema.

Possibly you were close on the `LEFT JOIN` approach:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT topic_id, topic_name
    FROM  topic T
    LEFT JOIN  book_has_topic BHT
           ON T.topic_id = BHT.topic_topic_id
          AND  BHT.book_book_id = [bookid]
    WHERE  BHT.book_book_id IS NULL
```

Note 3 changes to `AND  BHT.book_book_id = [bookid]` -- shange to `AND`, move to `ON`, change tok `=`.

But this probably still needs `DISTINCT`.  Hence using a "semi-join" (`EXISTS`) is more efficient.